# Calculate distance and duration in Google Maps v2 throught Google Direction API

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I used Google Direction class (shared public on internet) to draw lines between two point.

```
public class Direction {

 public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
    public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

    public Direction() {
    }

    public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
        String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?"
                + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
                + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude
                + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getDurationText(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDurationValue(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getDistanceText(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
        Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
        return node2.getTextContent();
    }

    public int getDistanceValue(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
        Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
        Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
        return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
    }

    public String getStartAddress(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getEndAddress(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public String getCopyRights(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
        Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
        Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
        return node1.getTextContent();
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection(Document doc) {
        NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
        ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
        if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                for (int j = 0; j < arr.size(); j++) {
                    listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
                }

                locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
        }

        return listGeopoints;
    }

    private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            if (nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;
        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng position = new LatLng(lat / 1E5, lng / 1E5);
            poly.add(position);
        }
        return poly;
    }
```

**Now I need to display distance and duration between them, but I don't know how to do it? Anyone can help me solve this. Thanks a lot!**